# Cookiebot by usercentrics - implementation in angular website

Tags: angular, cookies, angular14, cookiebot

I'm trying to use Cookiebot (https://www.cookiebot.com/) on our angular (Angular 14) website and I'm running into problem. I assign the data-cookieconsent="ignore" attribute to the blocked by Cookiebot scripts. This causes that cookies are setting before user consentt, which is contrary to the GDPR rules. Have You any advice how to resolve this issue?

I tried to use @halloverden/ngx-cookiebot, problem was the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.